# Выбор элементов, атрибут которых содержит подстроку

Tags: jquery

Есть ли в `jQuery` возможность отобрать элементы, атрибут которых содержит некоторую подстроку? Как с `contains`, только для значения атрибута.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такой селектор **[jQuery( "[attribute*='value']" )](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)**

```js
 
$( "input[name*='man']" ).val( "has man in it!" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="man-news">
<input name="milkman">
<input name="letterman2">
<input name="newmilk">
```

---

Регистронезависимый поиск:

```js
$("input[name*='man' i]").val( "has man in it!" );
//                   ^------------
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="mAN-news">
<input name="milkman">
<input name="letERMAN2">
<input name="newmilk">
```

Comment: Возможен ли регистронезависимый поиск?

Comment: @nup есть. дописал второй пример

Comment: Все бы хорошо, только с модификатором `i` не хочет искать внутри элемента:
https://jsfiddle.net/1r08t453/

Ни через `find`, ни так.

Comment: В примере ошибся - поместил `i` вне скобок, если поместить внутри, как раз и начинает возникать ошибка: `Syntax error, unrecognized expression`.

Comment: @nup ну есть сигнатура, которая чётко определена документацией. Логично, что попытка сделать что-то не так, как показывает документация работать не будет

Comment: @nup для `$("input[data-name*='man' i]", $('body'))` логично будет  `$("body  input[data-name*='man' i]")` или `$("body > input[data-name*='man' i]")`. Для find возможно тоже можно найти подобную замену